# Sharepoint 2016 people picker

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker

I have a problem with SharePoint on-prem 2016 people picker: Our client dont want to open any unsecure ports like 389. Is there any way to configure people picker work only with port 636?

Adding users to sites is very difficult without possibility to resolve users with people picker.

Antso

Comment: Thank you Trevor. It seems to be hard to add users even manually without people picker thats resolving accounts. Only way so far is to ask users login site once, but problems for creating personal sites and some other functions still exists. Wish I could convince importance of tcp/389, even that security is of course important.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Usage of tcp/389 is baked into the SharePoint code for the People Picker.

Answer (score 1):

I had a project with a similar issue. We ended up writing our own ClaimsProvider.

Our case didn't match exactly your problem. We had to use UserProfileService as user base, as we were not allowed to communicate with ActiveDirectory in any way.

We started digging into the problem with this article:
[Fixing People Picker for SAML Claims Users Using LDAP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/05/26/fixing-people-picker-for-saml-claims-users-using-ldap/)